# GPlus SignIn in Android: Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson returns null ONLY on 3G

Tags: android

I am using Google Sign In for my android app. On trying to retrieve profile info and display name of the signed in user, I see that the Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson returns null **only when I am on 3G** (mobile data).

I do see that the email address is retrieved correctly (using Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient)) and so are all the people in my circle .... it is only the getCurrentPerson that is null thus not letting me access getCurrentPerson.getDisplayName().

This works **perfectly fine on a wireless internet** connection and I am able to retrieve all Person details including email and display name.

I have already checked to make sure the right GPlus APIs are included on the developer console, the SHA1 signature matches up and every other possible suggestion I could find online.

Wondering what is different when connected on a 3G network that only getCurrentPerson is not retrieved. Appreciate any help! Thanks!

My code:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .build();

 Person gplusPerson= Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
  if (gplusPerson!=null)
  {
      loggedInUser=gplusPerson.getDisplayName();
  }
  loggedInUserEmail= Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Comment: Please, can some one help? Have been struggling with this one!